# Remove everything outside specific value in brackets in a string PHP

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I am trying to find a solution on how to remove everything outside specific value in brackets, including the value in brackets.
This is what I mean. I have this string

```
$str = "[:de]Some german text[:en]Some English text[:]";
```

What I want to achieve to get the text between [:de]and[:en] and to remove everything else, so the result has to be

```
$str = "Some german text";
```

I guess it should be some preg_match or some regex solution, but all I found was, how to remove the text in between, but not to keep the text in between and remove everything else.

Any ideas are welcome.

Comment: The question should be rolled back and posting your own answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess,

```
(?<=\[:de\]).*?(?=\[:en\])
```

might work OK here.

#### Test

```
$re = '/(?<=\[:de\]).*?(?=\[:en\])/s';
$str = '[:de]Some german text 1[:en]Some English text[:] [:de]Some german text 2[:en]Some English text[:]
[:de]Some german text 3[:en]Some English text[:]';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

var_dump($matches);
```

#### Output

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(18) "Some german text 1"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(18) "Some german text 2"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(18) "Some german text 3"
  }
}
```

---

If you wish to simplify/modify/explore the expression, it's been explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/AHMVH9/1/). If you'd like, you can also watch in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/AHMVH9/1/debugger), how it would match against some sample inputs.

---

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Emma, that helped a lot. I will edit my answer with a little simple solution I came with based on your response.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Emma's answer this is what I came up as a solution.

```
$re = '/(?<=\[:de\]).*?(?=\[:en\])/s';
$result = preg_match($re, $str, $match);
$result = $match[0];
```